# Retrieve array list from Oracle stored procedure - Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve a list of objects from a Stored Procedure in Oracle SQL. May you know how can I get an Arraylist from the code below?

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("P_ROUTES");
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
   .addValue("V_FIXED_INT", period)
   .addValue("V_CARRIER", carrier)
   .addValue("V_DATE_RANGE_START", dateRangeStart)
   .addValue("V_DATE_RANGE_END", dateRangeEnd);
 Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
 ArrayList obj = (ArrayList) out.get("RET_CURSOR");
 Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) obj.get(0);
```

In map object I have the list of key - value pairs.
Check image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that is the best solution but it works for me. I ll try to find something better. If you have any other suggestion feel free!

```
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
ArrayList obj = (ArrayList) out.get("RET_CURSOR");
logger.info("Length of retrieved routes from database = " + obj.size());
for (Object o : obj) {
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) o;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
        routes.add(entry.getValue().toString());
}
```